# When calling the recursive function in Lua, print() does not seem to work properly

Tags: function, recursion, printing, lua

I am calling a recursive function in Lua. The results I want are as follows.

0.016666666666667
wait
0.033333333333333
wait
0.05
wait
0.066666666666667
wait
result

However, the results are as follows.

0.016666666666667
0.033333333333333
0.05
0.066666666666667
result
wait
wait
wait

The code is as follows. I ask for your understanding first. I'm a beginner at Lua. And I looked for it a lot, but I couldn't get the answer I wanted. Can someone help me?

```
seconds = 0 
user_wait = function()
    
    seconds = seconds + (1/60)
    print(seconds)
    if seconds <= 3/60 then
      user_wait()
      print("wait")
    else
      seconds = 0
      print("result")
      return 1
    end
    
  end
  
  user_wait()
```

Comment: Swap `user_wait()` and `print("wait")`

Comment: Also, you should write `return user_wait()` in the function to use *tail call optimization*. Otherwise a stack overflow would occur after a few thousand calls.

Comment: Thankyou~ Egor Skriptunoff, prapin